# Adding Argo CRD Validations to vscode

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, argoproj

Based on the instructions in the Argo docs here: https://argoproj.github.io/argo/ide-setup/, I know that you can easily add it to intellij validation settings but there is no help on how to add the CRD YAML templates to vscode.

I would like to add the CRD validation yamls from Argo to my vscode settings to get the necessary validations and auto-complete but I can't figure out how to use a YAML within my `"yaml.schemas": {...` section (using RedHat YAML extension) when it's a YAML file as opposed to a JSON schema.

So I guess my question is essentially, how do I replicate the yaml CRD validation settings that are currently available in intellij?

Comment: they mention VSC as a possible editor to use, add an issue to update documentation on how to setup in VSC

Answer (score 1):

VSCode instructions is now added to [the documentation](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/ide-setup/#vscode), in summary:

1. Install the Red Hat YAML plugin in VSCode and open extension settings
2. Open the YAML schema settings
3. Add the Argo schema setting `yaml.schemas`, this may look something like:

   ```json
   "yaml.schemas": {
     "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/api/jsonschema/schema.json": "my/argo-files/**/*.yaml"
   }
   ```